# Parsing starting points of concated files

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, concatenation, glob

I have 3 csv files in 3 different folders that I need to merge and then do averages on values of each individual line (there is about 4000 lines in each file.

I have managed to combine panda dataframe with glob and access file needed. However, when I concate the files, the order is different than I want to.

[image]

```
path = '/home/alispahic/1.CB1_project/12.Production_Runs/'
all_files = glob.glob(path + '*/3.IVa*/rmsf.csv')

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    data['Atom']=data['Atom'].astype(int)
    data['(nm)']=data['(nm)'].astype(float)

    df1=data['Atom']
    df2=data['(nm)']


    li.append(df2)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

What I want to do is to have an output where the order of values of these files will not be just merged into one column, but rather have 3 columns of 4000 rows and access values like that.

Comment: Except that my pandas 0.23 does not allow a `np.array` for the first parameter of `pd.concat`, this code should leave the rows in the order they were in the original file. Could you give precisions, example data, or better a [mcve] to better explain what you currently get and what you would expect?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you for pointing that out. I have just realised that I had a mistake in the code I uploaded. Bear in mind that I am quite new in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate along the column axis to get 3 columns:

```
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an easy fix!